# Attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'num1' (a string value)

Tags: lua, roblox

So I have been working on a ROBLOX calculator game, and I got this error in console when making it:

`attempt to perform arithmetic on global 'num1' (a string value)`

I can't figure out how to fix it, I am still fairly new to lua so if somebody can help me with this that would be great. This is my code:

```lua
num1 = script.Parent.Parent.num1.PlaceholderText
num2 = script.Parent.Parent.num2.PlaceholderText
opadd = nil
while true do
    num1 = script.Parent.Parent.num1.PlaceholderText
    num2 = script.Parent.Parent.num2.PlaceholderText
    opadd = ((num1) + (num2))
    script.Parent.Text = opadd
end
```

Edit: Now if I attempt to change `opadd = num1 + num2` to `opadd = tonumber(num1) + tonumber(num2)` it gives me the error message:

```lua
Players.DemonicDevy0.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.LocalScript:7: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value
```

Which I am guessing means changing the string values num1 and num2 to numbers using tonumber(string) it acts as if tonumber(string) is all one variable and says it's a nil value.

Comment: If this still haven't been solved, have you tried adding `.Value` to the end of `PlaceholderText` as you may currently be assigning the object `TextLabel` instead of the number it holds to the variables. Converting an object to a number will return nil, giving you your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`num1` and `num2` are strings. You're taking them from a text object. To convert them to numbers, simply put `tonumber(num1) + tonumber(num2)` instead.

Comment: nvm there is a new error `Players.DemonicDevy0.PlayerGui.ScreenGui.TextLabel.LocalScript:7: attempt to perform arithmetic on a nil value`

Comment: I'm guessing now that I am using tonumber(stringvalue) it thinks I am trying to add 2 nil values together

Comment: Confusing. Could you `print(num1)` and `print(num2)` before and after you enter the while loop?